# shortcut to out-of-box of bracket

Tags: visual-studio-code

On vscode, there's a shortcut to go to inner of outer bracket .

```
    report_disk_space() {
        return
    }
```

**Mac** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

From the command palette, there's `select to bracket` going to the outer of the bracket.
yet there's not keyboard binding.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a keybinding for this. Open the keyboard shortcuts file and append the following code in the user keybindings. Save the file and VS Code will select the bracke if you do `ctrl+k` followed by `ctrl+\`. You can change the keybinding by editing the value of the `key` property.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+\\",
    "command": "editor.action.selectToBracket",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: This is JavaScript Object Notation(JSON)

Comment: In case anyone is not able to find this command in the VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts settings page by searching using it's name in the text box, then you will have to manually add this shortcut in the keyboard shortcuts JSON file. To open the JSON file click on the page icon with a arrow pointing to itself, located below the minimize window button in the upper right side corner. Then add the shortcut as described by @Chirag Bhansali in his answer.