# shortcut of select to bracket in the command Palette

Tags: visual-studio-code

There's a `select to bracket` in the command Palette

```
cmd + shift + p
```

However, there's no keyboard binding.

How to bind it to shortcut saying 'ctrl + m'

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595253/shortcut-to-out-of-box-of-bracket/49597321#49597321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit keybindings using the Keyboard Shortcuts Editor.

Mac: Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (cmd + k, cmd + s)

Windows: File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: In case anyone is not able to find this command in the VS Code Keyboard Shortcuts settings page by searching using it's name in the text box, then you will have to manually add this shortcut in the keyboard shortcuts JSON file. To open the JSON file click on the page icon with a arrow pointing to itself, located below the minimize window button in the upper right side corner. Then add the shortcut as described by @Chirag Bhansali in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open the keyboard shortcuts file with the command palette(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) and append the following code in the user keybindings. Save the file and VS Code will select the bracket if you do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+m",
    "command": "editor.action.selectToBracket",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```